# How to assess "reliability" for a non-stationary time series compared to a reference

Tags: time-series, correlation, inference, reliability, methodology

I have two arterial pressure measurement devices, one of which is the reference. My goal is to assess reliability compared to the reference and the variables (demographics, passing time, etc.) characteristics influencing this relationship. The measurement consists of a pair of time series with one sample per 5 seconds over 10 minutes.

Given the need to assess multiple potential influencing variables including passing time, I am thinking of building some kind of multiple regression model on the delta between sample pairs, but I am lost from here on.

What are the established techniques geared towards such questions, please?

Comment: Some elements of this question require scientific judgment: exactly how would you measure the comparative "reliability" of two such series?  Presumably, not every one of those 120 samples is of equal value and you are somehow condensing them into a decision to take some kind of action.  How exactly is that decision based on the data?  BTW, what is a "passing time" in terms of these time series data?

Comment: @whuber Well, of course I could consider each sample pair as independent events and draw a Bland-Altman plot, but then I lose all time information, which may be important if for instance measurements tend to diverge more with "passing time" (i.e. interaction with time from start of measurement). The 120 samples hold identical importance, and there is no decision or resulting action. This is a purely inferential problem. Essentially, it's only to assess whether the new method can replace the old within some acceptable marginal error bounds.

Comment: Yes, but replace the old in what sense?  To make any inference we need a basis for comparing two such series and that will ultimately require a *single* numerical valuation of their difference.  That basis cannot be offered through statistical reasoning *in vacuo:* it is essential to know the use or purpose of the comparison.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for taking the time to help me, but unfortunately I do not quite understand. Would you be able to provide me with an example of what you mean by such a "use or purpose of the comparison" so that I can try to improve my question, please? What I can say is that the old device is considered replaceable based on the mean and standard error of the delta between the two measurements by the  competent authorities.

Comment: I would have a hard time being realistic about that because I have only the vaguest idea of what this device is or how it is intended to be used.  I imagine it could have many uses for medical monitoring and diagnosis.  For some of those uses the replacement might turn out to be better and for others the original might be better.  In such cases, with no clear winner, you will make a trade-off regardless of what you do (keep the old or adopt the new).  Although statistical thinking can help *guide* people in making such tradeoffs, the answer ultimately is subjective.